# How to mock a class being imported from a npm module

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am importing a class via `const { PaymentRequest } = require("react-native-payments");` and I am trying to mock the functions it exposes when it is instantiated. For example:

```
const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS, OPTIONS);
    paymentRequest.canMakePayments().then(res => {...})
```

I want to mock this and change the value coming back from the promise resolve so that I can test different scenarios from `canMakePayments` and other async functions the class exposes.

Comment: I did not understand, sorry, can you explain what do you mean by mock

Comment: Do you mean its a local class, but the import must look like from node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you can use `jest.mock` method mock `react-native-payments` module manually.

`index.ts`:

```js
const { PaymentRequest } = require('react-native-payments');

const METHOD_DATA = [
  {
    supportedMethods: ['apple-pay'],
    data: {
      merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.com.your-app.namespace',
      supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard', 'amex'],
      countryCode: 'US',
      currencyCode: 'USD'
    }
  }
];

const DETAILS = {
  id: 'basic-example',
  displayItems: [
    {
      label: 'Movie Ticket',
      amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '15.00' }
    }
  ],
  total: {
    label: 'Merchant Name',
    amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '15.00' }
  }
};

const OPTIONS = {
  requestPayerName: true
};

function main() {
  const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS, OPTIONS);
  return paymentRequest.canMakePayment();
}

export { main, METHOD_DATA, DETAILS, OPTIONS };
```

`main` function is going to be tested.

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main, METHOD_DATA, DETAILS, OPTIONS } from './';
const { PaymentRequest } = require('react-native-payments');

jest.mock('react-native-payments', () => {
  const PaymentRequestMocked = {
    canMakePayment: jest.fn()
  };
  return {
    PaymentRequest: jest.fn(() => PaymentRequestMocked)
  };
});

const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS, OPTIONS);

describe('main', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    paymentRequest.canMakePayment.mockReset();
  });
  it.each`
    value               | name
    ${'mocked value 1'} | ${'t1'}
    ${'mocked value 2'} | ${'t2'}
  `(`$name`, async ({ value }) => {
    paymentRequest.canMakePayment.mockResolvedValueOnce(value);
    const actualValue = await main();
    expect(actualValue).toEqual(value);
    expect(paymentRequest.canMakePayment).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/57565053/index.spec.ts
  main
    ✓ t1 (5ms)
    ✓ t2 (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.03s, estimated 6s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57565053